# Same data variable passing to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project, I have one search section with 3 select box. I passed the value to it using

```
$data['restaurant_all']=$this->restaurant_model->get_all('','','','','','yes')->result();
$data['state_all']=$this->state_model->get_all();
$data['menu_all']=$this->menu_model->get_all('all','','','','','','yes')->result();
$data['restaurant']=$this->input->post('restaurant');
$data['state']=$this->input->post('area');
$data['food_type']=$this->input->post('menu');
```

I need this statement in all my pages. In there any way to accomplish this without writing these statements in all the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. extend the default controller by creating a file MY_Contoller.php at a suitable location.

b. create a custom class that will extend the default controller.

c. add a protected or public variable $data to custom class.

e. do something with data using __construct()

d. make every controller extend the custom controller.

e. you can access this variable like any other class variable.

example code:

MY_Controller.php

```
class APP extends CI_controller {
        protected $data;

        function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->_init();
        }

        function _init() {
                $this->data['state'] = $this->input->post('area');
        }
}
```

normal controllers:

```
class Welcome extends APP {

        function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
        }            

        function view() {
               /* pass this data value like normal data param */
               $this->load->view('some_view', $this->data);
        }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I got this solution already. But it doesn't work at the first time because I created the file in application/libraries folder. But when I changed that to application/Core it worked for me. However thank you for your answer

Comment: glad it worked for you.

also, make sure when using CI 2.x; extend all core classes in application/core folder

Answer (score 0):

Use constants, in `/config/constants.php`